# Maven - repo.spring.io is giving 404 for spring milestone dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Unable to download spring-boot-starter-parent-2.4.0-M1 jar with maven today (July 6th, 2022)

This is giving 404.
https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.4.0-M1/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.4.0-M1.pom

any quick resolutions?
Note: Can't switch to new versions immediately.

Comment: milestones will be published, but the problem is simply you are not allowed to access the spring repositories anymore (https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020)...if you like to consume a milestone you can use that via central repositories... https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies

Comment: Why are you even using a milestone, and such an old milestone. You should at least be able to use something else, a final, in the 2.4 range instead of this old one.

Answer (score 2):

Spring repo is down at the moment. See https://twitter.com/springops/status/1544719860340428800?s=20&t=0KUlqQe7S4Hh2fcH0ElF9w

Comment: Spring repo is made up now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if other that spring are publishing the milestones.
You can use your own maven repository and publish that version to stay fixed.
Otherwise, you need to point to the 2.4.0 version of that same artifact.

Comment: Will think of using my own repository. But, it's tedious.
Hope spring/jfrog fixes the issue soon.

Comment: If you are on an organization, and need a repo for publishing internally your own packages, then you can use your own and use as proxy/mirror of the other, for cases like this. For this case can be a workaround anyway.